# How would you determine if a generic type interface is implemented for a variables type (not a pre-known type)?

Tags: c#, generics

I have an array of objects which implement generic interfaces e.g.

```
public class BaseEvent {}

public interface iResponder<in T> where T: BaseEvent
{
    void respondToEvent(T event)
}
```

And a few implementations e.g.

```
public class UpEvent : BaseEvent {}

public class DownEvent : BaseEvent {}

public class UpResponder : iResponder<UpEvent> {}
{
    respondToEvent(UpEvent event) {}
}
public class DownResponder: iResponder<DownEvent> {}
{
    respondToEvent(DownEvent event) {}
}
```

If I create an array of objects which varyingly implmement these interfaces (so a bunch of UpResponders and DownResponders).  I also have a list of Events which are Up or Down and are run through in an array. I can query to see if a specific interface is available using

```
//pre-existing
List<BaseEvent> myEventsList;
List<object> myRespondersList;

foreach (BaseEvent nextEvent in myEventsList) 
{
    foreach (nextResponder in myRespondersList) 
    {
        if (nextResponder is iResponder<UpEvent>)
        {
            iResponder<UpEvent> castResponder = nextResponder as iResponder<UpEvent>;
            nextResponder.respondToEvent(nextEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

However I would much prefer to get the type of the BaseEvent (e.g. UpEvent) and identify if the object implments the interface without having to try each known type.  E.g.

```
//pre-existing
List<BaseEvent> myEventsList;
List<object> myRespondersList;

foreach (BaseEvent nextEvent in myEventsList) 
{
    // get the type here
    System.Type eventType = nextEvent.GetType();
    foreach (nextResponder in myRespondersList) 
    {
        // eventType cannot be used to define the interface required 
        if (nextResponder is iResponder<eventType>)  // - this will not work
        {
            iResponder<eventType> castResponder = nextResponder as iResponder<eventType>;
            nextResponder.respondToEvent(nextEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

I have found ways to identify if an object implements a generic interface and other tricks, but nothing I can piece together to make this work.

I have tried specifically creating lists for each listener type (which would provide better performance for what I'm doing) but this just moves the problem - at some point I need to see if an interface is implemented for an object for which I only know the type at runtime.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Would it be possible to make the interface non generic and just have it declared as `void respondToEvent(BaseEvent event)` instead? Do you need to know the exact type T is inside the function?

Comment: It would be possible, however an object may be able to respond to a number of events and I was hoping to have a method for each of them, rather than a large switch.  It would also be handy to be able to determine if a object would listen for certain events - I guess I could handle this with a respondTo type method, but was hoping to make it intrinsic with the interface.

Comment: Many thanks for the solutions provided so far - I'll try them all and decide which is better for my use case, however each of them has taught me something more about the language, huge thanks to all!

Answer (score 1):

The `Type` class has a method `GetGenericArguments` which will return an array of the types used to specialize the generic type, letting you filter on matches to the supplied `eventType`:

```
foreach (var responder in myResponderList)
{
    var typeArgument = responder.GetType().GetGenericTypeArguments().FirstOrDefault();
    if (typeArgument == eventType)
    {
        // dynamic invoke via reflection - a few lines of code
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can get the `MethodInfo` for the `RespondTo` method and check the parameter types. You'll have to get this anyway to do the dynamic invocation, so might as well go straight there:

```
var method = responder.GetType().GetMethod("RespondTo", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
var expectedType = method.GetParameters().FirstOrDefault()?.ParameterType;
var eventType = nextEvent.GetType();
if (expectedType.IsAssignableFrom(eventType))
    method.Invoke(responder, new[] { nextEvent });
```

We can wrap all of this in a non-generic parent interface to make the code a little more compartmentalized. It's not going to stop the reflection and dynamic invocation any faster though.

Ideally you want to do as little reflection as possible. If you can't avoid it then you should try to cache the results so that you don't have to do it frequently. Or find a way that works *without* reflection, preferably without a lot of work.

#### Zero-Reflection using abstract base class & interface

Let's add a non-generic interface and use it as the base for your generic interface like this:

```
interface iResponder
{
    void RespondTo(BaseEvent evt);
}

interface iResponder<T> : iResponder
    where T : BaseEvent
{
    void RespondTo(T evt);
}
```

Now we can implement an abstract base class to handle the type filtering:

```
abstract class ResponderBase<T> : iResponder<T>
{
    public void RespondTo(BaseEvent evt)
    {
        if (evt is T realEvent)
            RespondTo(realEvent);
    }

    public abstract void RespondTo(T evt);
}
```

And finally, your responder classes now derive from that base:

```
class UpResponder : ResponderBase<UpEvent>
{
    public override void RespondTo(UpEvent evt)
    {
        // do something.
    }
}
```

Organising the code this way means never having to do reflection. Your dispatch loop turns into:

```
List<BaseEvent> myEventsList;
List<iResponder> myRespondersList;

foreach (BaseEvent event in myEventsList)
{
    foreach (iResponder responder in myRespondersList)
    {
        responder.RespondTo(event);
    }
}
```

Since we're using the interfaces you can re-implement the base class in an external library, or handle things differently in a concrete implementation of the interface.

Comment: A great answer, many thanks - I think I need to implement this alongside the other solutions, I think it looks like the right solution for my use case.

Comment: You need to make `abstract class ResponderBase<T> : IResponder<T>` also implement `IResponder` or make `IResponder<T>` inherit from `IResponder` to make the final code example work.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yep. Thought I fixed that, apparently did not. Well spotted.

Answer (score 0):

One possible option is to use a non generic interface that can report if the type is handled or not.

```
public interface iResponder
{
    void respondToEvent(BaseEvent event)
    bool supportsEvent(BaseEvent event)
}
public interface iResponder<in T> : iResponder where T: BaseEvent
{
    void respondsToEvent(T event)
}
```

You then implement the classes using a explicit interface implementation.

```
public class UpResponder : iResponder<UpEvent>
{
    public bool respondsToEvent(BaseEvent event) {
        return event is UpEvent;
    }

    void iResponder.respondToEvent(BaseEvent event) {
        respondToEvent((UpEvent)event);
    }

    public void respondToEvent(UpEvent event) {}
}
public class DownResponder : iResponder<DownEvent>
{
    public bool respondsToEvent(BaseEvent event) {
        return event is DownEvent;
    }

    void iResponder.respondToEvent(BaseEvent event) {
        respondToEvent((DownEvent)event);
    }

    public void respondToEvent(DownEvent event) {}
}
```

And have your function look like

```
//pre-existing
List<BaseEvent> myEventsList;
List<iResponder> myRespondersList;

foreach (BaseEvent nextEvent in myEventsList) 
{
    foreach (iResponder nextResponder in myRespondersList) 
    {
        if (nextResponder.respondsToEvent(nextEvent)) {
            nextResponder.respondToEvent(nextEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

You also could remove the RespondsToEvent function and just put the is check inside the explicit methond and not call the derived version at all if the type check fails.

Comment: This is also a great answer, many thanks.  I suspect I will fall back on having a respondsToEvent type method, but was hoping this could be worked out intrinsically in the interface.  But this is very clean and so not difficult to make use of.  Will implemnet and compare with the other suggested methods for my use case.

Comment: Instead of saying thanks in a comment, upvote any and all answers you found to be helpful. It helps people stay engaged in the community.

Comment: Will do and tried - I don't have enough reputation yet!

Answer (score 0):

Handling generic types with reflection is often annoying and complicated. If you want to use reflection, maybe because you don't want to introduce a new interface (like the other answer). I find it easier to wrap all the generic handling into a single method, then use reflection to call that method.

For example;

```cs
public void ProcessEvent<T>(T eventObj) where T : BaseEvent
{
    List<object> list = null; // TODO
    foreach (var handler in list)
    {
        if (handler is iResponder<T> responder)
            responder.respondToEvent(eventObj);
    }
}

public void ProcessBaseEvent(BaseEvent eventObj)
{
    var method = new Action<BaseEvent>(ProcessEvent).Method
        .GetGenericMethodDefinition()
        .MakeGenericMethod(eventObj.GetType());
    method.Invoke(this, new object[] { eventObj });
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer (as well as the others so far) - many thanks - I need to implement to see how it works properly.